# Android - Securely communicate web site with native app

Tags: android, security, android-webview, schema, communication

I want to expose a deeplink in my app to perform certain functionality

I know this can be don through schemes (ex. market://details...)

However I want to only give access to this functionality to selected websites; any other website or app trying to use this should be denied.

Which is the best way to achieve this, if possible at all. Should I send some kind of public/private key to the request?

Answer (score 0):

just link it against ur own website, like :

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
     <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
 </intent-filter>
```

then only that website (on the example http://example.com) will be able to launch the app

Comment: But I would like it to be compatible with various websites, that may appear after the app is published

Comment: Is it possible to build this intent-filter programmatically? so that a service may update the list recurrently?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You must specify on your manifest all your filters during development.